# Jhipster Material not working

Tags: jhipster

Hello Hipsters I tried to generate **jhipster-material** application but it's showing the following error

```
 $ yo jhipster-material
C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-material\generators\app\index.js:64
  configuring: {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.get [as jhipster-material:app] (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\store.js:40:23)
    at Store.get (C:\Users\mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\store.js:64:35)
```

I installed generator-jhipster-material from here [github: generator-jhipster-material](https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-material)

I'm using **jHipster version 4.0.0**, **node version 6.9.4** and **yarn version 0.19.1**

Can anybody help me how to make it work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

generator-jhipster-material has not been ported yet to angular 2, this is a big work as JHipster 4 is based on Bootstrap 4 which overlaps with Material Design. It means that basically all templates (HTML + CSS) have to be reworked.

Comment: Thanks. I searched the whole internet to figure that out. Its nowhere mentioned. However if we go with agular-material separtely, will it work??

Comment: angular-material is rather intrusive, so it means many changes in JHipster templates  which are based on Bootstrap. Maybe a lighter approach would be to use a Material Design library based on Bootstrap llike mdbootstrap. Alternatively, PrimeNG seems to have some popularity in JHipster community.